# Various background color combinations for different tabs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to use different color combinations of `background-color` on different tabs selection.

For example:

- about: red `.nav-tabs`, dark red for `.active`,
- services: yellow `.nav-tabs`, dark yellow for `.active`,
- ....
- ....

and so on.

So what would be the best practice to achive this? I have a plan:

1. Pre-define styles for background colors,
2. Get the hash on `'shown.bs.tab'` event,
3. Pass it into a `switch` statement,
4. Set `.nav-tabs`and `.active` css.

Any better, a more practical idea?

**EDIT:**

To be more clear, what I am expecting is if I select `about` tab, the whole tab panel and other pills will be red and active `about` pill will be dark red. If I select `services`, tab panel and all pills will be yellow and active `services` pill will be dark yellow.

Comment: Its.not clear what you want to achieve.Can you post relevant code please.

Comment: @Hemant Ok, I am editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.You can add more `li` elements and add `classes` according to the color you want.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li:first').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('darkgreen');
    $('ul').find('li').not(this).toggleClass('green');
  })
  $('li:nth-of-type(2)').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('darkred');
    $('ul').find('li').not(this).toggleClass('red');
  })
})
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition:0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.green {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.darkgreen {
  background: darkgreen;
}

.darkred {
  background: darkred;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>about</li>
  <li>services</li>


</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Sorry but somehow it's a bit glitchy with click event [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/me2r17qw/1/)

Comment: That can be improved if you target the right element.:)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the

> siblings()

function in jQuery https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Give you tabs classes that represent the color. You can take the next line as an example.

```
$(".active").css("color", "blue").siblings().css("color", "darkerblue");
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a more practical procedure more than methods.